# get_template_part() - post-meta not working?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, loop, get-template-part

Maybe I simply do not understand what `get_template_part()` is doing …

I have a file called `event-list.php` that should work as template for other pages and files so all my events (a custom post type) get listed!

Inside this `event-list.php` I have this …

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $wr_event_fields = get_post_custom();
    $event_date_timestamp = $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_date'][0];
    $event_date = strftime('%d.%m.%Y', $event_date_timestamp);
    $event_time = $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_time'][0];
    $event_speaker = $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_speaker'][0];  
    //get_template_part( 'event-item' );
?>
    <!-- event-item.php -->
    <div id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <div class="event-date"><?php echo $event_date; ?></div>
        <div class="event_time"><?php echo $event_time; ?></div>
        <div class="event-speaker"><?php echo $event_speaker; ?></div>
        <div class="event-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        <div class="event-description-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

    </div>
    <!-- event-item.php -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So what I want to do is include another template inside of `event-list.php` named `event-item.php` which only holds the layout of an event. I want to use this `event-item.php` maybe later also in different loops. It should just be the markup for each single event-item on my website. If I make a change inside of this `even-item.php` template all "events" in any of my loops on my entire website should change.

The problem I have with this is the one in the above sample code.
I use `get_template_part( 'event-item' );` to include the `event-item.php` layout structure within my loop. And I get its custom post-meta outside of this template. However that does not work!

As you can see in my sample above I have to copy the entire layout structure from my `event-item.php` inside of my `event-list.php` so the post-meta stuff is filled in.

Any ideas what I don't get here or what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try globalizing `$post` inside of `event-item.php`.

Also: be sure to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after you close your `$loop` while loop.

e.g.:

```
<!-- event-item.php -->
<?php 
// globalize $post
global $post; 
?>
<div id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <div class="event-date"><?php echo $event_date; ?></div>
    <div class="event_time"><?php echo $event_time; ?></div>
    <div class="event-speaker"><?php echo $event_speaker; ?></div>
    <div class="event-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div class="event-description-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

</div>
<!-- event-item.php -->
```

and then:

```
<?php 
endwhile; 

// Restore $post global to the primary query
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

#### Edit

Assuming the problem is *just* the post meta data, I would suggest moving the post meta data variables *inside* `loop-item.php`. Only a guess, but perhaps your local variables aren't getting passed through the `include()` function that is part of `get_template_part()`.

So, like this:

```
<!-- event-item.php -->
<?php
// Define these here, inside loop-item.php
$wr_event_fields = get_post_custom();
$event_date_timestamp = $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_date'][0];
$event_date = strftime('%d.%m.%Y', $event_date_timestamp);
$event_time = $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_time'][0];
$event_speaker = $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_speaker'][0]; 
?> 
<div id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <div class="event-date"><?php echo $event_date; ?></div>
    <div class="event_time"><?php echo $event_time; ?></div>
    <div class="event-speaker"><?php echo $event_speaker; ?></div>
    <div class="event-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div class="event-description-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

</div>
<!-- event-item.php -->
```

**Also**, to avoid `undefined variable` notices, you should define your variables using `isset()` conditionals; e.g. change this:

```
$event_date_timestamp = $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_date'][0];
```

...to this:

```
$event_date_timestamp = ( isset( $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_date'][0] ) ? $wr_event_fields['_wr_event_date'][0] : false );
```

Comment: Thank you, sounds good, but unfortunately doesn't work for me … any other thoughts? Wordpress in debug mode always says … `Notice: Undefined variable: event_date in /Users/m2/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/blank/event-item.php on line 11`

Comment: First things first: do you get any output for `the_ID()` and/or `post_class()` prior to that `$event_date` undefined variable? If you *are*, then the problem is with your local variables; if you're *not*, then there's something else wrong.

Comment: See updated answer, that assumes the problem lies *only* with your post custom meta data variables.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing:

```
get_template_part( 'event-item' );
```

do this instead:

```
get_template_part( 'event','item' );
```

`get_template_part` expects the filename will be: `parameter1-parameter2.php`

Also make sure that you declare the variables you want to use as globals, else they will be out of scope and not be shown:

```
global $event_date, $event_time, $event_speaker;
```

Comment: As I read the OP, it's not about how to include a file *via* `get_template_part()`, but rather, why the global `$post` object/data aren't available to template tags, such as `the_ID()`, called *within* the included template-part file.

Comment: But `the_ID()` calls the global `$post` object already. Hm.

Comment: @chip Exactly … 
@toscho `get_template_part( 'event','item' );` does load the same file (event-item.php) but doesn't change the fact that the post-meta is not loaded inside the template.