# get_template_part() isn't loading author information

Tags: post-meta, get-template-part

Using `get_template_part()` I parted some of my theme's common post templates. My post template is `content-general.php`. Without parting thing is going fine. But just after parting the template — using `WP_DEBUG, true` — I discovered it's showing some **errors** in loading author information:

> **Notice: Undefined variable: authordata**

Along with:

> **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

I have the following code, where I have **`$authordata`**:

```
<a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'your-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>">
   <?php the_author(); ?>
</a>
```

I followed [this WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49285/get-template-part-post-meta-not-working) and tried globalizing `$post` inside the template file (`content-general.php`) like:

```
<?php global $post; ?>
```

and the template is called within a default WordPress loop. But the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this answer with good practices, by Chip Bennett, in mind](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49302/22728) just do a simple global thing — add `global $authordata` to your template file:

```
<?php global $authordata; ?>
```

Follow the Codex's **[Global Variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables)** article for details about the `global` practice.

Quoting the portion specific to the Question:

> `$authordata` (`object`) Returns an object with information about the author, set alongside the last `$post`.

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `the_post()` up front in the template part?

Comment: I have `the_post()` in the index file, with the loop: `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); get_template_part( 'content','general' ); endwhile; ?>` - till we need to define it again, in the template part? If I do so, then last post (LIFO) got vanish.